# Why is the optional add-in not showing as a separate tab on the ribbon?

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, office-addins, ms-project

**Used by:**

- MS Project 2016 Pro Desktop;
- Visual Studio 2019 Community;

  **Problem:**
  I installed the add-in "Add-in-1" in MS Project.
  I created the "Add-in-2" add-in project.
  I start debugging the Add-in-2 add-in.
  Result: "Add-in-2" is displayed on the same tab as "Add-in-1".
  [image]

**Description:**

- **"Add-in-1"** 
  I created an add-in.
  I did not debug the add-in in Visual Studio.
  I installed the add-in.
  Result:
  Picture
   [image]
- **"Add-in 2"**
  I created an add-in.
  I did not install the add-in.
  I am running add-in debugging in Visual Studio.
  Result:
  "Add-in 2" in Visual Studio
    [image] 
  "Add-in 2" in Visual Studio. Debugging
    [image]

**The note.**
 I planned to do:
 - Project "Add-in-1" - display on the tab "Tab-1" (or display on several tabs);
 - Project "Add-in-2" - display on the tab "Tab-2" (or display on several tabs).
 
**Question.**
1. Why add-ons "Add-in-1" and "Add-in-2" are not displayed on separate tabs?

---

### Update 1

I made a change.
Add-in-2. Ribbon renamed. The current name is `Ribbon1Test`.
Add-in-2. tab1 renamed. The current name is `tab1Test`.
Add-in-2. tab1. ControlID renamed. The current name is `TabAddInsTest`.

**Add-in-2. Ribbon.** 
[image]

**Add-in-2. tab1**
[image]

**Add-in-2. tab2.**
[image]

I am running debugging.
**Add-in-1. tab1.** 
[image]

**Add-in-2. tab2.** 
[image]

**Result:** No Add-in-2. tab1.

Comment: Is the `controlId` property of your RIbbonTab different ? It has to be.

Comment: @Malick See `Update-1`

Comment: so is it solved ? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Malick I did not understand your question.
Could you formulate it in more detail.
Problem: doesn’t appear when using
`Add-in-2. tab1`.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, because now you correctly have two different ribbon menu and each has its own ribbon group. So to me there is no problem: "Add-in-1" and "Add-in-2" *are* displayed on separate tabs .I don't understand what do you mean by "doesn’t appear when using Add-in-2. tab1".

Comment: @Malick Problem: during debugging, the tab1Test tab of the Add-in-2 add-in is missing. When I start debugging I see the following tabs:
- `"Add-in-1"` - `tab50` - the tab is present;
- `"Add-in-2"` - `tab1Test` - there is no tab on the tape;
- `"Add-in-2"` - `tab2` - the tab is present.
See the last two pictures.

Did I manage to clarify the question?

Comment: Yes, you clarify and it is another problem but sorry I don't know the answer. It is very strange, maybe you could try to remove both add-ins completely from excel, do a clean - rebuild and see if the problem persists.